# VBA Run time error 91 when executing code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on a spreadsheet where column 23 (w) is keeping track of column AA which is a day counter. When the day counter reaches over 14, then column 23 (w) will say the word "Overdue" and my code will send out an email to say it is overdue. I am using a formula to make the cell read overdue, hence why I am trying to use _Calculate in my code. But when I try and manipulate the day tracker to read overdue, I get the following error, and I don't know why.

> Runtime error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range

    If target.Column = 23 And target.Value = "Overdue" Then
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
            .To = "Harrywood@company.com"
            .Subject = "Item OverDue"
            .Body = "Dear User," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "An Item has been marked as Overdue. Please open up the workbook to assess."
            .send
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You declare `target`as `Range`-variable but don't assign anything to it.

Comment: Is it just a single cell that could read "Overdue"? In that case, why not use `If Cells(i, 23).Value = "Overdue" Then` with `i` being the right row number.

Comment: unfortunately it cannot be a single cell. As there will be multiple items that get inputted on the sheet. I have done conditional formatting all the way to cell 2000

Answer (score 2):

Worksheet_Calculate has no Target argument. You may be mashing up some related Worksheet_Change code.

Since Target is not being passed into the Worksheet_Calculate, you decided to Dim it but never assign (Set) any cell or range of cells to it.

Target is Nothing and Nothing has no column or Value property.

You might try looping through the values in column W to see if any are *Overdue* but that might mean that duplicate emails would be sent out. Perhaps set up another column where TRUE/FALSE indicates whether an email has already been sent.

Assuming that column Z is unused you could use that to indicate whether an overdue email has already been sent. This method survives closing and reopening the workbook so long as the changes are saved when closing.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range(Cells(2, "W"), Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp))
        If LCase(rng.Text) = "overdue" And Not rng.Offset(0, 3) Then

            With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
                .To = "Harrywood@company.com"
                .Subject = "Item OverDue"
                .Body = "Dear User," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "An Item has been marked as Overdue. Please open up the workbook to assess."
                .send
            End With

            rng.Offset(0, 3) = True
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether another column with T/F for 'email already sent' or an array of static values that indicate new 'Overdue' values would be a better choice. I might need feedback from the op before recommending one method over another. BTW, Worksheet_Change doesn't trigger on a change in the result from a formula.

Comment: column z is in use for users to input the "date closed". so that when column C "date in" has been inputted and column Z hasn't then "overdue" can be applied when the counter reaches over 14 days. If the counter reaches over 14 days then users put a closed date in Z, then column W will read "complete". I do not have a column that says the email has been sent, i guess I can add one in though

Comment: Well, a static array of Overdue (to see what changes to Overdue and was not already Overdue) can be set up to be reread when a workbook opens but it is convoluted. The Overdue seems to be generated by a formula that depends on a 'counter' or some volatile function like TODAY() or NOW(). I think a new column is the more straightforward and your best bet.

Comment: Your code works really well, but I am getting a new runtime error 13 on the line If Lcase(rng) = "overdue" And Not rng.offset(0,3) then

Comment: rng is each of the cells in column W. Offset moves that over 3 columns to column Z. If you changed my column Z to another column then you need to change the offset so rng.Offset(0, 3) is reading a TRUE/FALSE from the cell.

Comment: Change it to `If LCase(rng.Text) = "overdue" And Not rng.Offset(0, 3) Then`

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `Selection_Change`, the `Calculate` event isn't associated with a target cell (the whole worksheet is calculated at once).  So your `target` object never refers to anything, hence the error 91 (which is Object variable not set).

There is a `Worksheet_Change` event (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) which does pass a `target`, but this is *not* triggered when a formula changes value, only when a user makes the change directly.  So this probably won't work for you.

I think you have two choices:

- if the change you want to track is caused by a user editing the sheet somewhere, then change your event handler to `Worksheet_Change`, look for the actual cell that the user changed (e.g. column AA), and then repeat the overdue calculation.
- if, as it seems, the change isn't caused by user input then you will need to modify your `Worksheet_Calculate`handler to loop through all the relevant cells and check for any with value "Overdue".